# Referencing a database in my android app

Tags: android, database

I have seen examples where a database is created upon launch of an activity. I would like to create a database and then have my activity reference it. My program will do searches on this database and display information depending on what the user specifies.

1. Are there any examples you can point me to?
2. I have read that if I'm in DDS mode, using the file explorer I can view the database file. I cannot see any file or folder inside data folder. My phone is not rooted, is this why I cannot see the files in data? How do I go about viewing the database file?

Comment: In DDMS, you should be able to see files inside /data/data if you are using an emulator or rooted device. If it's a non-rooted device, you'll have to use code in your app to copy the database from internal storage to external since only your app itself has permission to read it.

Comment: Thank you NigelK. I just read a note about copying the database from internal storage storage using adb on non-rooted device. Instead of copying it afterwards, what if I was create the database in external storage from the get go? How would I specify this in my program?

Comment: You should not ask such common questions which you can easily google returning 1000's of results.

Comment: @hkg Yes, I believe you can define your database on external storage (not a good idea for released code - no security and external storage may not be available). As MuhammadA points out, such questions have been asked many times before so please just search first and then ask for help once you've got some code built.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best example I ever found...

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html